# Bem-vindo, bem vindo ou benvindo?

Tags: ortografia

Qual é a forma correta de receber bem uma pessoa?

> bem-vindo

ou

> bem vindo

ou

> benvindo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bem-vindo é grafado com hífen e o último acordo ortográfico não alterou esta escrita.
De acordo com o estudioso do Português [Claudio Moreno](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/06/02/bem-vindo-2/):

> O acordo não mudou nada quanto a isso; vamos colocar um hífen depois
>   de bem sempre que ele se ligar  a um vocábulo que tenha existência
>   autônoma no nosso idioma: bem-estar, bem-falante, bem-aventurado,
>   bem-querer, bem-vindo, etc.

O autor continua esclarecendo o uso do hífen:

> Aqui, mais do que em qualquer outro lugar, ficam evidenciadas as duas
>   funções que o hífen acumula, pois ele é, ao mesmo tempo, um sinal que
>   separa e um sinal que une (o famoso traço-de-união): em bem-vindo, ele
>   sinaliza (1) que estamos diante de um vocábulo uno, embora composto, e
>   (2) que os dois elementos que entram em sua composição têm vida
>   própria.

E por fim cita casos onde não se usa o hífen:

> É exatamente por isso que não temos hífen em benfazejo ou 
>   benquisto; embora não seja difícil reconhecer ali a presença do
>   radical de fazer e de querer, respectivamente, não temos mais, como
>   formas livres, *fazejo ou *quisto.